# Emit data with EventBus

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pass an object using EventBus in Vue.JS but it's not working.

I created the event-bus.js file like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
const EventBus = new Vue()
export default EventBus
```

Then in my file A I imported it

```
import EventBus from 'components/event-bus.js'
```

Then I'm firing the event bus with a click event. The click event it's working.

```
likeQuestion(question) {
      EventBus.$emit('likedQuestion', (question) => {
        console.log(question)
      })
    }
```

And here in file B, I want to get the data passed in the bus, so I imported the EventBus just like I did in file A and finally I'm trying to get the data with Mounted.

```
 mounted () {
    EventBus.$on('likedQuestion', function (question) {
      console.log(question)
    })
  },
```

But it's not working, the console.log doesn't even show up in console. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: can you try to access the data with a `watcher` and not per `mounted`

Comment: I'm not sure it would work. What I want in the end is to push the "question" into an array of objects that is created in file B

Comment: Is the `B` component mounted before you emit the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `emit` payload should be a data not a callback function :

```
likeQuestion(question) {
      EventBus.$emit('likedQuestion', question)
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but in file B I still can't get the payload

Comment: Try out with kabeb-case format like `$emit('liked-question'` and `$on('liked-question'`